# Matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot: Using colors with eventplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I would like to use eventplot to colors some 1D points according to theirs labels.
Here is a minimal example of what I would like to do:

```
my_arr = [1.5, 2.4, 5.6]
my_colors = ["g", "b", "g"]
plt.eventplot(my_arr, colors=colors1)
```

and here is the stacktrace I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-0a7ce5b07a8c> in <module>
     12 my_arr = [1.5, 2.4, 5.6]
     13 my_colors = ["g", "b", "g"]
---> 14 plt.eventplot(my_arr, colors=colors1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in eventplot(positions, orientation, lineoffsets, linelengths, linewidths, colors, linestyles, data, **kwargs)
   2620         linelengths=linelengths, linewidths=linewidths, colors=colors,
   2621         linestyles=linestyles,
-> 2622         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2623 
   2624 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1436     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1437         if data is None:
-> 1438             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1439 
   1440         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in eventplot(self, positions, orientation, lineoffsets, linelengths, linewidths, colors, linestyles, **kwargs)
   1460                              'sequences')
   1461         if len(colors) != len(positions):
-> 1462             raise ValueError('colors and positions are unequal sized '
   1463                              'sequences')
   1464         if len(linestyles) != len(positions):

ValueError: colors and positions are unequal sized sequences
```

I have checked the doc as well as several topics but couldn't figure it out.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the issue here is that, from the docs: "A 1D array-like defines the positions of one sequence of events.", so it expects only one color.

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve here with eventplot?
Is there a betterway to do a 1D scatterplot with points colored with respect to theirs labels?
I tried several solution but, if producing a 1D scatterplot seems quite straightforward, coloring the points the right way seems more tedious...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe like `plt.eventplot([[1.5], [2.4], [5.6]], colors=["g", "b", "g"], lineoffsets=[1]*3)` ?

Comment: @JohanC A bit late but thank you, that was what i was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

The positions variable `my_arr` should be a list of lists, where each inner-list contains events that belong on the same color group.
The color variable `my_colors` should then list each color just once, so that `len(my_arr)==len(my_colors)`. The code below should work:

```py
my_arr = [[1.5, 5.6], [2.4]]
my_colors = ["g", "b"]
plt.eventplot(my_arr, colors=my_colors)
```

To make it look 1D, you may wanna add `lineoffsets=0` to the inputs to `eventplot`:

```py
plt.eventplot(my_arr, colors=my_colors, lineoffsets=0)
```

(typo alert: you seem to refer to `my_colors` later with a different name, `colors1`)